# How to SELECT using LIKE on entire column, but not require exact match?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a partial match `SELECT` on two tables using entire columns instead of specific characters or wildcards.

I have two tables (T1, T2) and two columns (T1.C1, T2.C2).  I am able to get a return on a `SELECT` when C1 and C2 are an exactly formatted match, however, C2 has strung together text that includes text string from C1.

So, as example here are a few examples of formatted characters in the two tables:

T1.C1

- Doe, John
- Smith, Steve
- Roberts, Sally

T2.C2

- #Doe, John, Thekid, Billy, Random Group A
- Random Group B, Smith, Steve# Jones, Allie
- #Roberts, Sally!Random GroupC, etc.

What I want to be able to do is match when 'Doe, John' from T1.C1 is found in T2.C2 even though in that table it's formatted as '#Doe, John, Thekid, Billy, Random Group A'

Here is what I'm using to get an exact match...

```
SELECT *
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.C1 LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.C2 , '%');
```

Comment: say, are you trying to select names but ignore the junk on the sides like the `#`? why not use LIKE % $search_value %

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT *
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T2.C2 LIKE CONCAT('%', T1.C1 , '%');
```

?
i.e, T2.C2 containing the string in T1.C1.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2 FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE t2.c2 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.c1,'%');

This matches the strings from both tables

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20df8/21

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it!  I think I had the tables reversed when working this earlier, and sequence matters.  Great forum, excellent resources :>)

Comment: You're welcome. I can't tell you how many times this site has saved my hide